# Viewport performance issues with top spec machine

Tags: particles, physics, performance

I am desperate for help.

I have a really good machine (Ryzen 3970x, Asus prime pro TRX-40 motherboard, 128gb G-Skill trident memory running at 3600, MSI gaming trio OC X 3090 on windows 10, optix with both CPU and GPU selected, GPU only on render output with light paths unchanged) running the latest Blender release 2.92 but preview is painfully slow - even in solid/wireframe view and even though the actual scene takes only seconds to render out.... like my machine can render an entire scene at 128samples quicker than it takes for a change to be affected in the solid mode viewport of that same scene (32samples)!!!!?????

While blender is working in viewport task manager says it’s only ever using 12gb of ram (of 128). The best it’s used is 35gb of 128gb

The CPU usage is quite high while baking but not in general playback or viewport work.

The GPU says it’s only being utilized between 1% and 12% at its heaviest???? And sometimes in viewport it’s not being utilized at all. (I have the latest nvidia studio drivers installed and the latest asus bios).

I’ve had no joy trying to bake and view any kind of fluid simulations and watch them in the viewport and while some my models are admittedly quite heavy (4m+ faces for some of the landscape) with lots of micro displacement, I’m sure my machine can do better in the viewport than it is.

1. I spend 2minutes or more waiting for simple changes to materials (normal bump or displacement). My mouse lags, blender is inactive between these changes.
   The minute I add a shrink wrap or constraint that effects the lower poly models the computer again slows down to an unusable pace.
2. Once I’ve applied a particle setting to any object (even simple faces) in a heavy modeling scene blender all but stops working.
3. I can’t watch fluid, smoke or particle! sims in a scene without it slowing to a very low FPS(like one or two frames per second instead or 24) even in solid or wireframe view.

Baring in mind this is before I’ve added any kind of geometry nodes or scatter objects (like trees or rocks) to the scene - which means if I try add anything like that to a scene that has particles or scatter or heavy matrials settings the machine is all but useless.

What could be the reason for this and is there a workaround or better workflow for models that (for instance) need a high very terrain? Like how do I work in physics, actions, characters with movement or cameras that track subjects a viewport when it is barely giving 1fps?

Would it be beneficial to scale the size of my models and scenes down in the scene properties panel (1 : 0.01 or something?) so I can continue working in real scale?

Would it help to remesh my heavy terrains once displaced?

IS THERE SOME MAGIC SETTING WHERE MY MACHINE STARTS USING A REASONABLE AMOUNT GPU, RAM AND CPU??????

Any help here would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You DON'T want he RAM to be fully used : if a program needs 12 Gb, it won't benefit for the extra 116 Gb. It's different for CPU and GPU, and I don't know how to help you, but you can put the RAM out of your equation.

Comment: Thanks to you both for this. I still live in hope that there is something I can do. I appreciate that the Ram isn’t powering performance in the viewport but I have heard reports of Ram being utilized at 85gb of 128 while rendering progressive animation frames... @ZurgalTheWizard, what would be your first choice for faster viewport responsiveness.

Comment: NVidia makes the best GPUs on the market.

Comment: Do you mean buy an Nvidia brand card instead of the MSI Nvidia?

Comment: I though the specs were matched with particular GPU?